# Using {{#each}} to fill a calendar with reservations: best practices

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm building an html table with dates as columns and hotel rooms as rows.

I'm fairly new to Meteor and have had headaches over this.

Because a html table is build by rows, I need to iterate over the rooms. So, if I am not mistaking this limits me to choosing the following file structure in MongoDB:

```
Room Collection:[
{Room1:[{"31/03/2015", "2/04/2015",....]},
{Room2:["22/03/2015",...]},
...]
```

Before this I had a reservation object where every reservation had the name of the room in it. Because there is no way I can group these dates over different collections, I changed it to the above structure.

So, okay, now I am able to move the cursor from room to room and build table rows.

Bigger problem now is that I then would iterate over 7 days (lets just say, for now I only retrieve queries for the current week). If I now get three days back from the database that are booked. I am only able to loop three times. Which is bad news because I need to fill 7 td elements. So somehow I should Identify which days of the week are taken by the reservation.

Is it a possibility to just store every date of the year in MongoDB and indicate wether there is a booking for that date? That seems far from elegant.

Or should I compare the dates of the week with the dates retrieved from the server, so on the client side?

I think I am looking at this problem the wrong way. I would love to here somebody else's opinion on this. :)

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always start off with an ER model of what I have & what I want.

How I think you currently have it: 1 Room has many Reservations. 1 Reservation has 1 datetime.

How you want to access it: 1 Day has many Reservations. 1 Reservation has 1 datetime & 1 room.

The Mongo way to do it: 1 Reservation has 1 room & 1 date.

So your original idea was correct (I'm not sure what you mean by not being able to group in other collections, we can tackle that in comments if you like):

```
Reservations = {
    name: 'The Johnson Family Reunion',
    room: 'Grand Ballroom',
    datetime: new Date
}
```

For simplicity, we'll assume you aren't changing months in this example & I assume you've already got the code down to assign days to those squares.

Each square in the calendar should follow a `dayofMonth` template.

That will afford you a `this` that has the date in your helper, so you can write something like this:

```
Template.dayOfMonth.helpers({
    reservations: function() {
        return Reservations.find({datetime.getDate(): 
        this.datetime.getDate()}).sort(datetime);
    }
}
```

Then, your template is something simple like:

```
{{#each reservations}}
    {{reservations.name}}
{{/each}}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the extensice reply! What I mean by combining collections is the following: dates are columns, rooms are the rows. So I need to "group" the different reservations that use the same room (but on different dates) in one row.

Comment: So, a cell represents all the reservations for a single room on a single day? Just add this to your query: `room === this.room`.

Comment: Yeah, kinda. But there can only be one reservation at a time in a cell of course. :) If I am correct I can group the dates over the different collections by using _.pluck from the underscore.js package. I think I have all the elements to move ahead! Thank you very much Matt.